# Manipulate the order of overlaping on svg elements

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, dom, d3.js

I have two g nodes "zones" and "selected-zones" on the same level
[image]

inside each there are a bunch of g nodes "polygon" which represent shaped objects inside parent svg node of "zones" and "selected-zones"
[image]
[image]

each "polygon" node has a foreign object which is used for editing text and its position inside "polygon"
[image]
[image]

the problem is that if a foreign object node is shown for a object inside "zones" it is displayed under any node of "selected-zones" because "zones" and "selected-zones" are on the same level and "selected-zones" goes after "zones" node in DOM structure which is a default svg behaviour
[image]
is there a way to manipulate the order in which nodes overlap others to make foreign object displayed on top of other nodes, besides placing it as a lastchild on the same level?
I've tried css `z-index` property but is seems to have no effect on svg nodes.

Comment: in order to put an svg shape on top of the others you need to move it at the end of the svg element. A way of doing it is by appending it with appendChild like in this pen: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YXoEQe

Comment: @enxaneta yes i undestand it, my question is there a way to put an svg shape on top of the others without changing DOM structure, like using z-index for simple html elements?

Comment: The simplest approach would be to create an additional <g> on top of both "zones" and "selected-zones" which is responsible for holding elements that are supposed to be on top. It could be called "zones-overlay" for example.

Comment: There is no z-index support in SVG 1.1 (the current base supported version in all browsers). While drawing order is the natural way to get layering support, there are two other ways to manipulate layering - one is to draw the element you want on top again, later in the DOM by doing a "use" element pointing to whatever you want to over-draw. Or you can explicitly manipulate order inside a filter when shapes are imported via feImage - but using a filter is rarely a good idea